# How to build *.so module in Automake and a libtool-using project?

Tags: shared-libraries, automake, libtool

I have the same problem as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916425/how-to-create-a-shared-library-so-in-an-automake-script) have:

- I have a `*.la` file generated by **libtool** in an **Automake** project (e.g. `module.la`),
- but I **need the `*.so`** of it to use it for `dlopen()` (eg. `module.so`).

But: project is configured and built with `--disable-shared` to make sure the created main binary is one big statically linked program, e.g. `main.x` (easier for deployment and debugging). Thus `*.so` files are not created.

The program `main.x` is a huge framework-like application which is capable of loading extensions (modules) via `dlopen()` -- despite it being linked statically.

This works fine when I build `module.so` by hand. But putting this to work in `Makefile.am` seems impossible to me. Yes, I can write `lib_LTLIBRARIES`, but with my standard `--disable-shared` I do not get a `*.so` file.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = module.la
module_so_SOURCES = module.cpp
```

The file `module.la` is created, which `dlopen()` refuses to load (of course).

I tried to put rules into `Makefile.am` building it manually and that works:

```
# Makefile.am (yes, .am)
all: mm_cpp_logger.so

SUFFIXES = .so

%.so: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -fpic -c -I $(top_srcdir)/include -o $@  $<

%.so: %.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -fpic -o $@  $<
```

But this can only be a workaround. I do not get all the nice auto-features like dependency-checking and installation.

How can I build `module.so` with still building the main program with `--disable-shared` (or with the same effect) in the `Makefile.am`-way?

- can I postprocess `*.la` files to `*.so` files with a special automake rule?
- can I tweak the `lib_LTLIBRARIES` process to create `*.so` files in any case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *[module](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Modules.html)*. You can tell Autotools to create a static binary (executable) by adding `-all-static` to the `LDFLAGS` of the application. I think this is the preferred way over using `--disable-shared` configure flag (which really is aimed at the libraries rather than the executable)

Something like this should do the trick:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS=-I$(top_srcdir)/include

lib_LTLIBRARIES = module.la
module_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -shared
module_la_SOURCES = mm_cpp_logger.cpp

bin_PROGRAMS = application
application_LDFLAGS = -all-static
application_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

The `.so` file will (as usual) end up in the `.libs/` subdirectory (unless you install it, of course).

And you can build both your application and plugins in one go (even with a single `Makefile.am`), so there is no need to call `configure` multiple times.

The use of `-fPIC` (and friends) should be auto-detected by Autotools.

---

***Update***: here's a little trick to make the shared-libraries available where you expect them. Since all shlibs end up in `.libs/`, it is sometimes nice to have them in a non-hidden directory.

The following makefile snippet creates convenience links (on platforms that support symlinks; otherwise they are copied). Simply adding the snippet to your makefile (i usually use an `-include convenience-link.mk`) should be enough (you might need an `AC_PROG_LN_S` in your configure.ac)

```
.PHONY: convenience-link clean-convenience-link

convenience-link: $(lib_LTLIBRARIES)
    @for soname in `echo | $(EGREP) "^dlname=" $^ | $(SED) -e "s|^dlname='\(.*\)'|\1|"`; do  \
        echo "$$soname: creating convenience link from $(abs_builddir)/.libs to $(top_builddir)"; \
        rm -f $(top_builddir)/$$soname ; \
        test -e $(abs_builddir)/.libs/$$soname && \
        cd $(top_builddir) && \
        $(LN_S) $(abs_builddir)/.libs/$$soname $$soname || true;\
    done 

clean-convenience-link:
    @for soname in `echo | $(EGREP) "^dlname=" $(lib_LTLIBRARIES) | $(SED) -e "s|^dlname='\(.*\)'|\1|"`; do  \
        echo "$$soname: cleaning convenience links"; \
        test -L $(top_builddir)/$$soname && rm -f $(top_builddir)/$$soname || true; \
    done 
        
all-local:: convenience-link

clean-local:: clean-convenience-link
```

Comment: Man, I had to jump through hoops by now because of libtool issues. I replaced `-all-static` at ''application'' with `-static-libtool-libs` at my other "convenience" libraries (not the one under our discussion) -- I had to do that because `dl_blahblah()`-stuff crashed the program when I did `-all-static` (I am quite sure that it was the culprit). Anyway: Alas, I still do get the `.libs/mm_cpp_logger.so` -- which I find a bit awkward when writing tests for the module. Loading it from `.libs/` seems... wrong. Is it normal that it always gets there, no matter what I do?

Comment: i updated my answer for a possible solution for getting the the libs available outside of `.libs`

Comment: @umläute: nice solution! Unfotunately, the clean part is not working, since all the files containing "dlname=(.*)" are deleted before the part is started (so grep does not return anything). I have hard-copied your snippet into my Makefile.am file

Answer (score 2):

I've solved a similar problem using the **[noinst_LTLIBRARIES](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Static-libraries.html)** macro.

The **noinst_LTLIBRARIES**  macro creates static, non installable libraries to be only used internally. all noinst_LTLIBRARIES static libraries are created also if you specify the **--disable-static** configure option.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtokenclient.la
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libtokenclient_static.la 

libtokenclient_la_SOURCES = $(TOKEN_SERVER_CLIENT_SOURCES) cDynlib.c cDynlib.h token_mod.h
libtokenclient_la_CFLAGS = @BASE_CFLAGS@
libtokenclient_la_CXXFLAGS = $(libtokenclient_la_CFLAGS)
libtokenclient_la_LIBADD = @B_BASE_OS_LIBS@
libtokenclient_la_LDFLAGS = @LT_PLUGIN_LIBS_FLAGS@ @LIBS_FLAGS@ $(TOKEN_SERVER_CLIENT_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)

libtokenclient_static_la_SOURCES = $(libtokenclient_la_SOURCES)
libtokenclient_static_la_CFLAGS = $(libtokenclient_la_CFLAGS)
libtokenclient_static_la_CXXFLAGS = $(libtokenclient_static_la_CFLAGS)

token_test_SOURCES = $(TEST_SOURCES)
token_test_LDADD = @B_BASE_OS_LIBS@ libtokenclient_static.la
token_test_CFLAGS = @BASE_CFLAGS@
token_test_CXXFLAGS = $(token_test_CFLAGS)
```

I use noinst_LTLIBRARIES static libraries for 2 reasons:

1. to speed up compile time I create static libraries to be used as intermediate containers for code that shall be linked against more than once: the code is compiled just once, otherwise automake would compile same source files once for each target
2. to statically link the code to some executable

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could work according to the libtool documentation for [LT_INIT](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html) is to partition your build into two packages: the main application and the plugins. That way you could (in theory) invoke:

```
./configure --enable-shared=plugins
```

and things would work the way you would expect.

Comment: Your answer gave me good keywords to google for and I found [a tutorial](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/libtool/plugins.html). Alas, that also seems to assume I build everything with `--enable-shared`. Has a couple of good hints, though. But the doc you pointed to does not mention "plugins". Packaged? This means an a sub-`configure.in`, right? Yes, that might work. The directory with the module would get its own `configure.in`, I guess?

Comment: Yes, exactly. By "plugin" I mean a dynamically loaded extension. They (the main application and extensions) would both get some kind of sub-configure to configure them.  Maybe you could just get away with only one sub-configure for the extensions.