# How do I create a shared library using autotools

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, autotools

I've created an autotools based package that generates a `libxxx.a` static library. What is the correct way to alter my `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files to create a `libxxx.so` shared library instead?

I did try following the instructions at:

[How to create a shared library (.so) in an automake script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916425/how-to-create-a-shared-library-so-in-an-automake-script)

I added `LT_INIT` to the end of my `configure.ac`, and replaced references to `libtest_a` with `libtest_la` in my `src/Makefile.am`

I then ran:

```
$ libtoolize && aclocal && autoconf && automake --add-missing && ./configure && make
```

which gets me a:

> /bin/bash: --mode=compile: command not found

error message. What appears to be happening is that the build system has forgotten to use a compiler.

These are the original `configure.ac`

```
AC_INIT([libtest], [1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"
AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT([src/Makefile])
```

and `src/Makefile.am` files

```
AM_CPPFLAGS=-I../include
lib_LIBRARIES = libtest.a
libtest_a = -version-info 0:0:0
libtest_a_SOURCES = \
```

And here are the updated versions

```
AC_INIT([libtest], [1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"
AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT([src/Makefile])
LT_INIT
```

and

```
AM_CPPFLAGS=-I../include
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtest.la
libtest_la = -version-info 0:0:0
libtest_la_SOURCES = \
```

respectively.

You'll notice the added `LT_INIT` in `configure.ac` and references to `libtest.la` instead of `libtest.a`, as well as the change to `lib_LTLIBRARIES` in `src/Makefile.am`

In both cases I've left out the value assigned to `..._SOURCES` as irrelevant to this discussion (as well as rather long).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shared library (.so) in an automake script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916425/how-to-create-a-shared-library-so-in-an-automake-script)

Comment: Could you post `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files (perhaps omitting irrelevant sections for brevity). Are you in fact using `libtool`? What does the `./configure --enable-shared` produce? BTW, a well written package using autotools, can add the infrastructure with `autoreconf -fvi`. The [autotools mythbuster](https://autotools.io/index.html) is a practical and up to date.

Comment: Don't put LT_INIT at the end.  Put it nearer the beginning, but after AC_INIT.